# How to get IP address / location of connecting visitors to my website, and show THEIR addresses to me?

Tags: javascript, php, web, location, geoip

i am looking for help in this problem. I know how to get IPv4 address in PHP code, like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

this is what i found as answer for many questions like this here, but if i go to the website, it only shows MY ip address, if my friend goes to the website he sees only his ip address. The thing is, i will have administrator interface on the website, and i need to determine the ip address of all connecting clients - either in php or javascript and display it on my website in the admin interface. On server apache is running. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Save them to the database table is an option ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want to get the user IP address and location of the IP address who is visiting your website and other details.

```
// get user details
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //user browser
        $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];     // user ip adderss
        $page_name = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];      // page the user looking
        $query_string = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];   // what query he used
        $current_page = $page_name."?".$query_string; 


    // get location 
        $url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=/*userapikey*/
        // you can get your api key form http://ipinfodb.com/
        ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."&format=json"));
        $country=$url->countryName;  // user country
        $city=$url->cityName;       // city
        $region=$url->regionName;   // regoin
        $latitude=$url->latitude;    //lat and lon
        $longitude=$url->longitude;

    // get time
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $time = date("H:i:s");
```

you can now store these in database it will tell you the location, user browser and which page he/she is using

Comment: I am not sure about one think. OK, i need to create a database where i will store the data (the IP address and/or the location of connecting users), but how will i tell the database to store all the values? I mean do i need to loop through somehow through the `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get all the values from it and than store them seperatly? I am a bit confused

Comment: you can store where value in the database by the sql querry. and the will be no need to run a loop for this.

Answer (score 2):

When someone visits the site, put the value of `$ip` in a database.

When you want to see who has visited the site, loop over the contents of the database and display them.

You'll probably also want to include a timestamp and delete old data periodically and/or ignore data over a certain age (such as 5 minutes).

Comment: In addition, you will probably also want to store their current location on the website. You can find that by looking at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: I am not sure about one think. OK, i need to create a database where i will store the data (the IP address and/or the location of connecting users), but how will i tell the database to store all the values? I mean do i need to loop through somehow through the $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get all the values from it and than store them seperatly? I am a bit confused

Comment: "how will i tell the database to store all the values" — Each time someone visits the page, you store the IP they used to visit it.

Comment: "do i need to loop through somehow through the $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get all the values" — No, the visitor's request will only be coming from one IP, so there is nothing to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both see your own IP because you're just parsing the IP of the visitor, you need to save this Remote Address in a table, then just do a query to retrieve the content put a limit on your query this is very important, and then just parse the result and here you go, a list of the vistors

Answer (score 0):

I needed to track ip address and location of visitors to my site, to identify fraud clicks in google adwords campaigns. This product does the job, unfortunately its not free. Please see if this would solve you issue.

http://www.opentracker.net/products/web-analytics/feature/ip-address-tracking